# How can I synchronize input HTML field at all times without using a button, keystroke or window load?

Tags: javascript

Where am I going wrong in trying to have the "City" input field always equal the "City Repeat" field?  I do not want to use a button, keystroke or window load event because a separate JavaScript file is going to populate the "City" field (Google Places).

```
var cityvar = document.getElementById("city");
var statevar = document.getElementById("state");
var cityrepeatvar = document.getElementById("cityrepeat");
var staterepeatvar = document.getElementById("staterepeat");
function syncronize() {
    cityrepeatvar.value = cityvar.value;  
    staterepeatvar.value = statevar.value;
  }

function valuechange() {
cityvar.addListener('cityvar_changed', syncronize);
statevar.addListener('statevar_changed', syncronize);
    }

syncronize();
valuechange();
```

And the HTML:

```
City    
<input id="city" type="text" size=5/></br>
State
<input id="state" type="text" size=5/> </br>
City repeat
<input id="cityrepeat" type="text" size=5 /></br> 
State repeat
<input id="staterepeat" type="text" size=5/>
```

This is my attempt at the change event suggestion but is now resulting in a "Cannot set property 'value' of null" error."  I tried moving the JavaScript to the footer and also triggering myFunction with a button, to no avail.  Any ideas?  The HTMl input fields DO have the ID of "state" and "staterepeat".

```
function myFunction(val) {
  var staterepeatvar = document.getElementById("staterepeat");
  var statevar = document.getElementById("state");
  staterepeatvar.value = statevar.value ;
}
```

My latest attempt is below.  I tried using this so the javascript runs only after the page loads but it did not work.  Where am I going wrong on this?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

addOnload(syncronize);
addOnload(valuechange);

function addOnload(newFunction) {
  var oldOnload = window.onload;
  if (typeof oldOnload == "function") {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldOnload();
      newFunction();
    }
  }
  else {
    window.onload = newFunction;
  }
}

var cityvar = document.getElementById("city");
var cityrepeatvar = document.getElementById("cityrepeat");

function syncronize() {
    cityrepeatvar.value = cityvar.value;  
  }

function valuechange() {
cityvar.addEventListener('input', syncronize);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use change event?

Comment: I tried this for a change event but received the error "Cannot set property 'value' of null"

Comment: What are `cityvar_changed` and `statevar_changed` supposed to be? Have you defined your own custom event types here somewhere? _“because a separate JavaScript file is going to populate the "City" field (Google Places)”_ - changing the value of an input field via script does _not_ trigger events such as `input` or `change`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code. First replace `AddListener` with `addEventListener` . Then change `cityvar_changed` to `input`. Below is the working code. Try running the snippet too.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var cityvar = document.getElementById("city");
    var statevar = document.getElementById("state");
    var cityrepeatvar = document.getElementById("cityrepeat");
    var staterepeatvar = document.getElementById("staterepeat");
    function syncronize() {
        cityrepeatvar.value = cityvar.value;  
        staterepeatvar.value = statevar.value;
      }

    function valuechange() {
    cityvar.addEventListener('input', syncronize);
    statevar.addEventListener('input', syncronize);
        }

    syncronize();
    valuechange();
}
```

```html
City    
<input id="city" type="text" size=5/></br>
State
<input id="state" type="text" size=5/> </br>
City repeat
<input id="cityrepeat" type="text" size=5 /></br> 
State repeat
<input id="staterepeat" type="text" size=5/>
```

Comment: how could I get your suggestion to execute only after page loads?  My failed attempt at doing so is above in my edits using addOnload

Comment: Put the above code inside window.onload function.

window.onload = function() {

}


I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this: HTML

```
City    
<input id="city" type="text" onKeyUp="setCity()" size=5/></br>
State
<input id="state" type="text" onKeyUp="setState()" size=5/> </br>
City repeat
<input id="cityrepeat" type="text" size=5 /></br> 
State repeat
<input id="staterepeat" type="text" size=5/>
```

and JS:

```
var city = document.getElementById('city')
var cityrepeat = document.getElementById('cityrepeat')
var state = document.getElementById('state')
var staterepeat = document.getElementById('staterepeat')

function setCity() {
  cityrepeat.value = city.value
}

function setState() {
  staterepeat.value = state.value
}
```

on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OarXXj?editors=1010#0

Basically, what we're doing here is setting the new value of #cityrepeat and #staterepeat every time you type into #city and #state, respectively. When you type in the #city text input, it fires the setCity() function every time you let a keyboard key up onKeyUp="setCity()" this function sets #cityrepeat to the same value as #city